# seaborn's displot: two edcf, 1 figure

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

Here is how I plot the ecdf of my data

```py
d1 = list(np.random.rand(10))
d2 = list(np.random.rand(10))

plt.figure()

sns.displot(d1, label='label1', color="b", kind='ecdf')
sns.displot(d2, label='label2', color="r", kind='ecdf')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Which gives:
[image]

However, my intension was to plot this on 1 figure, for ease of comparison. Similar to the figure below:
[image]

Comment: Add an identifying column to each dataframe and then combine the dataframes with concatenation. Use the new column for hue. Otherwise, use sns.ecdfplot not sns.displot

Comment: can you please put this in an answer?

Comment: It’s a duplicate. I’m just finding the ones to close it to

Comment: it doesn't answer my question. That's talking about two plots (figures) side-by-side. In my case, I want it in just a single plot.